# How to calculate change in a column based on date across groups?

Tags: r, dataframe, date, dplyr

I have got a dataframe in R looking somewhat like the following example dataset `df`, below.

```
# Load package
library(tidyverse)

# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Step 1 (ignore)
temp_ref <- tibble(date = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2016-01-01")),
                   var = rnorm(3),
                   label = "REF")

# Step 2 (ignore)
temp_main <- tibble(date = as.Date(c("2019-05-05", "2018-05-05", "2017-05-05", "2016-05-05", "2015-05-05")),
                    var = rnorm(5),
                    label = "MAIN")

# Final example dataframe
df <- rbind(temp_ref, temp_main)

df

# A tibble: 8 × 3
  date           var label
  <date>       <dbl> <chr>
1 2020-01-01 -0.560  REF  
2 2018-01-01 -0.230  REF  
3 2016-01-01  1.56   REF  
4 2019-05-05  0.0705 MAIN 
5 2018-05-05  0.129  MAIN 
6 2017-05-05  1.72   MAIN 
7 2016-05-05  0.461  MAIN 
8 2015-05-05 -1.27   MAIN
```

What I need is to subtract the values of `var` in group `"REF"` from the values of `var` in group `"MAIN"`. To do so, I first need to find the closest date in `"REF"` prior to the date in `"MAIN"`.

Think of it like calculating the change of a variable from one measurement instance to the next (how did var change?) but across groups.

Expected outcome:

```
# A tibble: 8 × 4
  date           var label var_new
  <date>       <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1 2020-01-01 -0.560  REF    NA    
2 2018-01-01 -0.230  REF    NA    
3 2016-01-01  1.56   REF    NA    
4 2019-05-05  0.0705 MAIN    0.300
5 2018-05-05  0.129  MAIN    0.359
6 2017-05-05  1.72   MAIN    0.16 
7 2016-05-05  0.461  MAIN   -1.10 
8 2015-05-05 -1.27   MAIN   NA
```

What would be the best and tidiest solution to this in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the ***rolling join*** on the two groups of `df`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  left_join(filter(df, label == "REF"),
            by = join_by(closest(date > date)), suffix = c('', '.y')) %>%
  mutate(var_new = ifelse(label == "REF", NA, var - var.y)) %>%
  select(-ends_with('.y'))

# # A tibble: 8 × 4
#   date           var label var_new
#   <date>       <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
# 1 2020-01-01 -0.560  REF    NA    
# 2 2018-01-01 -0.230  REF    NA    
# 3 2016-01-01  1.56   REF    NA    
# 4 2019-05-05  0.0705 MAIN    0.301
# 5 2018-05-05  0.129  MAIN    0.359
# 6 2017-05-05  1.72   MAIN    0.156
# 7 2016-05-05  0.461  MAIN   -1.10 
# 8 2015-05-05 -1.27   MAIN   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution would work...

```
#calculate distance matrix
min_distances <- as.numeric(df$date) - matrix(rep(as.numeric(temp_ref$date), nrow(df)), 
                                              ncol = length(temp_ref$date), 
                                              byrow = T)
#in order to get only earlier dates, set everything to Inf which has later date
min_distances[min_distances<0] <- Inf
#keep track of those with only later dates to correct later.
ind_no_earlier_date <- apply(min_distances, 1, 
                            function(a) length(unique(a)) == 1 & is.infinite(a[1]))

closest_ind <- apply(min_distances, 1, FUN=which.min)
#build new var and correct REF and later dates only entries    
df$var_new <- df$var - temp_ref$var[closest_ind]
df$var_new[df$label == "REF"] <- NA
df$var_new[ind_no_earlier_date] <- NA
df
```

...but it is not really "tidy"

Comment: Looks good and works. I'm still working on a tidy solution... Let's see...

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that there are no consecutive days with `REF` (which may not be true in your real data, but it might help nonetheless).

Output arranged by `date`:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(ind = consecutive_id(label), #group by consecutive occurrences 
         ind2 = ifelse(label == "REF", lead(ind), ind)) %>% 
  group_by(ind2) %>% 
  mutate(ref_last = first(var),
         no_of_rows = n(),
         var_new = ifelse(label == "MAIN" & no_of_rows > 1, var - ref_last, NA)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-ind, -ind2, -ref_last, -no_of_rows)  
#   date           var label var_new
#   <date>       <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
# 1 2015-05-05 -1.27   MAIN   NA    
# 2 2016-01-01  1.56   REF    NA    
# 3 2016-05-05  0.461  MAIN   -1.10 
# 4 2017-05-05  1.72   MAIN    0.156
# 5 2018-01-01 -0.230  REF    NA    
# 6 2018-05-05  0.129  MAIN    0.359
# 7 2019-05-05  0.0705 MAIN    0.301
# 8 2020-01-01 -0.560  REF    NA
```